# Microsoft Access Database instead of SQLite or Local Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, portable-database

Does a Microsoft Access Database is a possible solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159697/need-to-save-a-lot-of-records-for-my-application-should-i-use-a-local-database) question? SQLite seems to be exactly what I want but I cannot make it work in the .NET framework 4.0.

I was thinking about using a Microsoft Access Database but I don't know if when deploying my application the database is going to be portable?

Do users need to have Microsoft Access installed in their computers if I plan to deploy my application with a Microsoft Access Database?

In case all this is possible and I decide to use a Microsoft Access DB where will I place the database?
As a resource and extract it when installing it?

Comment: What is the problem that you have with SQLite?

Comment: Yes, You can use mdb file. But I would prefer sqllite or sql compact.

Comment: See filip-fku's answer. I have never been happy when using Microsoft Access on any project. Never. It will burn you later if you choose to go this route in terms of rewriting queries for other database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had problems using SQLite using with the provided .NET assemblies.. As an alternative you could try using Microsoft's SQL Server CE, which is a lightweight database designed for deploying to clients. I don't see why you'd use Access db instead of either of the other two..

Comment: or maybe I am missing other assemblies. I have not been able to work with .NET Framework 4.0 and SQLite . Any suggestions on what assemblies I need in order to make it work will be nice

Answer (score 1):

The Jet database engine is installed on every copy of Windows beginning with Windows 2000, so if you use MDB format, you don't have to install anything to have access to a Jet MDB file.

If, however, you use ACCDB format, you'd have to install the ACE.

Answer (score 0):

Filip-fku thanks to your answer I found how to work with SQLite and the .Net framework 4.0 in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605490/system-data-sqlite-net-4)